# Why OFDM is more appropriate with MIMO than other multiple access method?

Tags: ofdm, lte

As read from [MIMO-OFDM](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/MIMO-OFDM) wikipidia page says

> Research conducted during the mid-1990s showed that while MIMO can be used with other popular air interfaces such as time-division multiple access (TDMA) and code-division multiple access (CDMA), the combination of MIMO and OFDM is most practical at higher data rates.

Why does OFDM has more higher data rates and they combined more advantaged? Thank you

Comment: You should probably read the papers cited in that article. Reads a bit too much like an advertisement to me.

Answer (score 2):

One possible answer is given at the beginning of the text:

> Raleigh suggested and later proved that the processing required by
>   MIMO at higher speeds would be most manageable using OFDM modulation,
>   because OFDM converts a high-speed data channel into a number of
>   parallel lower-speed channels.

Also:

> MIMO-OFDM is a particularly powerful combination because MIMO does not
>   attempt to mitigate multipath propagation and OFDM avoids the need for
>   signal equalization.